# How to do Android Unit Test using Appium in Ubuntu

Tags: android, python, unit-testing, ubuntu-12.04, appium

I want to do a simple unit test for HelloWorld Android application using Appium. My Android application has one Activity and after it loads on the screen, it displays "Hello World" on a TextView. What I want is to write a unit test case using Python that it works as I expect and test using Appium.

The main thing I cannot understand is the connection between my Android project, Appium and Python script.

I think I have configured Appium in my Ubuntu-12.04 correctly. When I give following command in terminal

```
anuja@anuja-MulTplx:~$ appium &
```

it gives following response

> anuja@anuja-MulTplx:~$ info: Appium REST http interface listener
>   started on 0.0.0.0:4723

I have written simple Python script for web unit testing with Selenium WebDriver. But I have no idea how to write a Python script to test my Android application using Appium. Need a example or good documentation.

Thanks

---

**I am adding this part after *@[Dan Cuellar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16817165/833007)* answer.**

After I have launched the server using one terminal, I ran my python script from another terminal which contains python bindings.

On the Appium server running terminal it gives following out put

```
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session

debug: Request received with params: {"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"app-package":"my.app.package","app":"/home/anuja/MobileDev/apks_and_keys/Trickbook.apk","browserName":"","version":"4.0.4","device":"Android","app-activity":"TrickbookSplasher"}}

info: Using local app from desiredCaps: /home/anuja/MobileDev/apks_and_keys/Trickbook.apk

info: Creating new appium session 4788d549-d39a-4730-9bdb-382418c2b2c9

info: Starting android appium

debug: Using fast reset? true

info: Preparing device for session

info: Checking whether app is actually present

info: Checking whether adb is present

info: [ADB] Using adb from /home/anuja/MobileDev/sdk/platform-tools/adb

info: Trying to find a connected android device

info: [ADB] Getting connected devices...

info: [ADB] 1 device(s) connected

info: [ADB] Setting device id to 4d017b1f209a3f7b

info: Found device, no need to retry

info: [ADB] Waiting for device 4d017b1f209a3f7b to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)

info: Checking whether we need to run fast reset

debug: Checking app cert for /tmp/my.app.package.clean.apk: java -jar "/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/app/android/verify.jar" "/tmp/my.app.package.clean.apk"

debug: App not signed with debug cert.

debug: Checking app cert for /home/anuja/MobileDev/apks_and_keys/Trickbook.apk: java -jar "/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/app/android/verify.jar" "/home/anuja/MobileDev/apks_and_keys/Trickbook.apk"

debug: App not signed with debug cert.

info: Building fast reset

error: uncaughtException date=Thu May 30 2013 11:28:22 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=4466, uid=1000, gid=1000, cwd=/home/anuja, execPath=/usr/bin/nodejs, version=v0.10.8, argv=[node, /usr/bin/appium], rss=27017216, heapTotal=19666944, heapUsed=12400392, loadavg=[0.26318359375, 0.201171875, 0.333984375], uptime=2427.250582503, trace=[column=18, file=fs.js, function=Object.fs.openSync, line=427, method=fs.openSync, native=false, column=15, file=fs.js, function=Object.fs.readFileSync, line=284, method=fs.readFileSync, native=false, column=36, file=/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js, function=ADB.buildFastReset, line=131, method=buildFastReset, native=false, column=12, file=/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js, function=null, line=311, method=null, native=false, column=14, file=/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js, function=null, line=283, method=null, native=false, column=7, file=child_process.js, function=ChildProcess.exithandler, line=641, method=exithandler, native=false, column=17, file=events.js, function=ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit, line=98, method=EventEmitter.emit, native=false, column=16, file=child_process.js, function=maybeClose, line=735, method=null, native=false, column=5, file=child_process.js, function=Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit, line=802, method=ChildProcess._handle.onexit, native=false], stack=[Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/app/android/AndroidManifest.xml.src',     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18),     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15),     at ADB.buildFastReset (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js:131:36),     at /usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js:311:12,     at /usr/lib/node_modules/appium/android/adb.js:283:14,     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7),     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17),     at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16),     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)]
```

AND on the terminal where I have executed the python binding script gives following out out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "forth.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 163, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 396, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)

httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I have used a self signed apk for above testing purpose.

- Right click on the Eclipse Android project
- Android Tools
- Export signed application package
- Go thorough the wizard

I am using a real device for this testing.

Can anybody point me where/what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`appium &` launches the appium server. Think of this as the equivalent of `java -jar selenium.jar` which would launch the Selenium RC server.

Once the server is launched you must connect to it via the python bindings:

```
from selenium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['device'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['browserName'] = ''
desired_caps['version'] = '4.2'
desired_caps['app'] = '/path/to.your.apk'
desired_caps['app-package'] = 'com.example.android.package'
desired_caps['app-activity'] = 'YourActivity'
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Once you've connected you can control the test via normal python webdriver commands.

Examples: https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/python

Comment: Thank for the response. I have stuck again while trying your method. I have edit my question according to your answer. Please look at after the horizontal line for new updates and let me know where/what I have done mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, `App not signed with debug cert.` your apk is not signed with the default debug cert in `~/.android/debug.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

Configure SDK like this

```
 export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/adt/sdk"

 export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"

 export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/tools

 export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/platform-tools
```

Code for reference:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

# Returns absolute path relative to this file and not cwd
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p))
class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        #Specify platform below(Android, iOS)
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        #Specify OS version(Settings->About phone -> android version)
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.4'
        #Obtain the Device name from Adb[For Android](Terminal Command: "adb devices")
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'TA93304QZD'
        #Specify the path to Application
        desired_caps['app'] = PATH('Media Drive-com.sandisk.scotti-55-v2.0.3.apk')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        # end the session
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_images_copy(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        for i in range(0,4):
                 self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Next").click()
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
           self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Close").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Photo").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
           self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/btn_Switch_Local").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
              self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Name").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```